# Circular permutation problem with married couples

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is the problem statement:

Find the number of ways to sit $n$ married couples around a table if every women is sitting next to her husband.

Since it' a circular permutation, I thought about looking at each couple as a single entity.

I would then have $(n-1)!$ ways of sitting down the couples. For each couple I would have $2!$ ways of sitting the man and the woman since that's just a normal linear permutation.

I then thought that the result would be $(n-1)!*2$, but the solution to the problem in the book is: $(n-1)!*2^{n}$ and I don't understand why.

This is the solution in the book:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you thought that we needed men and women to alternate *and* spouses to sit together.  Those were two separate problems.  All the problem wanted here for the answer of $(n-1)!\times 2^n$ was for spouses to sit together but it was perfectly fine for in some instances the husband to sit to the right of their wife and in other instances the husband to sit to the left.  $M_1W_1M_2W_2W_3M_3W_4M_4M_5W_5$ would have been a perfectly valid result here.

Comment: Alternatively, when you say "*For each couple I would have 2!
 ways of sitting the man and the woman since that's just a normal linear permutation*" you incorrectly stopped at only applying this thought process to the first couple and forgot to apply it also for the second couple and the third and so on... We multiplied by $2$ as a result of the first couple.  We then multiply by $2$ *again for the second couple*, and *again* for the third and so on... giving $(n-1)!\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2 = (n-1)!\times 2^n$ as expected.

Comment: thank you, I got it now